# Invalid url prefix nginx

Tags: nginx

Hi I am trying to start nginx with this config.

```
   server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  location /graphql/ {
    proxy_pass      http://localhost:18000/graphql;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;


  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }


}
```

But I am getting this error

```
2019/09/06 14:23:22 [emerg] 1#1: invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:11
nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:11
```

I am not sure what I am missing?

Comment: Not a duplicate; the other poster was using a unix socket without the protocol. This might be the same problem but a different cause.

Comment: Could there be non-printing characters or a character encoding problem? Check a Hex/ASCII dump of the config.

Comment: if your uri is already /graphql/ if you proxy_pass  http://localhost:18000 ; it will bring the whole uri with it, and not only "graphql".  /graphql/foo/bar will proxy_pass to /graphql/ and not to /graphql/foo/bar with your config.